# Silent Installation of MSI Package with many prompts (Parameters)

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have a MSI package that I need to install if the package is not already installed. Also I need to install it silently. I can use silent installation command for installing the package.

Silent installation will not ask me following parameters

```
Installation location (C:\Program Files\Foobar)
Install type: minimal and full (minimal)
```

It will pickup default values & install the package. But in my case the MSI package asking for some other parameters & for getting that parameters from users it launches a window (other java application). Please note that this window is not a part of the installation wizard pages. After entering the details the wizards moves to next page.

I am not able to avoid the prompt of this window using silent installation script.

Comment: Could you provide the command you are using for silent installation.

Comment: I am using following command for silent installation:   

msiexec /i setup.msi transforms=setupTransform.mst /q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pass values to public properties. These are all uppercase and semicolon-delimited in the `SecureCustomProperties` property in your MSI package.

But if you're package is throw up dialogs even when installing it silently, you need to contact the package owner and tell them to fix it. There's really nothing you can **safely** do to avoid it as the package author just bungled it horribly.